# How do I make friendy URLs in ASP.NET MVC with all products in the root?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm in the process of building a web shop in ASP.NET MVC. What I would like to accomplish is a list of all the products in the root of the web shop. In other words I would like a SEO optimized friendly URL with the names of the products directly after the base URL. For example:

myexamplewebshop.com/beautiful-red-coat

myexamplewebshop.com/yellow-t-shirt

If you click on one of these links, you will see the details page of the product. I guess I need to change something in the routing code somewhere to make this work. Can anyone give me an example of how to accomplish this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a route like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "SEO_Product", // Route name
     "{seoterm}",
 new { controller = "Product", action = "LookupBySEO" }
);
```

Then in your Product Controller add method:

```
public ActionResult LookupBySEO(string seoterm) {

    // convert URL encoded seoterm into product name

    // lookup product by name

}
```

This route should be added before the default route. 
NOTE: Every other page on your site cannot be on the root level anymore, i.e. /aboutus, /home, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add a [custom route](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs) to your RegisterRoutes function.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
                "ProductFriendly", // Route name
                "{productId}", // URL with parameters
                new {  controller = "YourProductControllerName", action = "YourProductActionName"  } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Would map to an action in a `YourProductControllerName` called `YourProductActionName`

```
public ActionResult YourProductActionName(string productId)
{
  // your code goes here...
}
```